# Why is my main breaker popping

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

So I have a 100A sub panel Box in my shop with its own 100A main breaker at the top of the box and has 5 240v
20A breakers and All together I'm only using 77A worth of equipment if all on at the same time and no 20A breaker has more than 18A if on all at the same time and all this is being fed by the main panel box with a 100A breaker for my shop  out side by the electric pole and this is a 200A box why does the 100A breaker outside pop 
But not the  100A breaker in the sub panel box in my shop

Comment: Have you actually measured this current or is it a guess based on equipment rating?

Comment: Welcome to DIY! I was going to edit your post because it isn't written very clearly but I couldn't make heads or tails where the 200A box came from. Please rewrite your post so it's clear how your power is setup without us having to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Is the feeder to your shop run overhead or underground?

Comment: What awg is the wire to the shop and how long is its run? How many extension cords are you using?